# std::pair<K,V> templated function not called template overloading not working

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-specialization, std-pair

Template Overloading not working in the current scenario.

I have a program of overloaded templates and a complex data structure having maps, pairs and vectors.
THe overloaded template function is not getting called for std::pair. 
I am unable to figure out the reason for it. It is calling #1 general template function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
template <typename T>
bool f(T& x) // #1
{
    std::cout << "body of f\n";
    return f(x);
}

template <typename T>
bool f(std::vector<T>& v) // #2
{
    std::cout << "body of f for vectors\n";
    return true;
}

template <typename Key, typename Value>
bool f(std::pair<Key,Value>& v) // #3
{
    std::cout << "body of f for pairs\n";
    for(auto& e: v) {
      f(e.first);
    }
    for(auto& e: v) {
      f(e.second);
    }
    return true;
}

template <typename Key, typename Value>
bool f(std::map<Key,Value>& v) // #4
{
    std::cout << "body of f for maps\n";
    for(auto& e: v) {
      f(e.first);  // expecting this call goes to #3
    }
    for(auto& e: v) {
      f(e.second);
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v{1,2};
  std::map<std::pair<int,int>,std::vector<int>> m_map = {
                                            {{10,20}, {5,6}},
                                            {{11,22}, {7,8}}
                                        };
    f(m_map); // this call goes to #4
}
```

Console Output  is

```
body of f for maps
body of f
body of f
body of f
body of f
body of f .... Goes on infinitely
```

Please let me know what is the problem with this code.

Thanks.

Comment: The "goes on infinitely" part is easy to explain: In the `template <typename T> bool f(T& x)` function when you call `f(x)`, the only known overload of `f` is itself. Which means you have an infinite recursion.

Comment: BTW, body of #3 is wrong, you cannot iterate on pair...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your `m_map` of type `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,std::vector<int>>` has a value type `std::pair<const std::pair<int,int>, std::vector<int>>`. Therefore, in `#4`, `e` is of type `std::pair<const std::pair<int,int>, std::vector<int>>&` and `e.first` of type `const std::pair<int,int>`.

`f(e.first)` will not call `#3`, since you cannot bind a non-const lvalue reference to a const object. If you change its parameter from `std::pair<Key,Value>& v` to `const std::pair<Key,Value>& v`, it will work. However, it will end up with a compilation error, since you cannot iterate with a range-based `for` loop over a pair. Change

```
for(auto& e: v) {
  f(e.first);
}
for(auto& e: v) {
  f(e.second);
}
```

to

```
f(e.first);
f(e.second);
```

in `#3`.

In the end, you are missing a final overload for `int`s to stop infinite recursion. Add something as:

```
bool f(int i) {
  std::cout << "body of f for ints\n";
  return true; 
}
```

Working [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lXooRJua9CnAUsxK).

Comment: @TechTotie You're welcome, and welcome on StackOverflow. Please note that we don't say things like "thank you" in comments. These are intended for useful on-topic discussions. Upvoting and accepting an answer is the best and enough way to say "thank you" indirectly :).

Answer (score 1):

iteration on `map` is done on `std::pair<const Key, value>`, so with

```
std::map<std::pair<int,int>,std::vector<int>> m_map;
```

you will call

```
f(const std::pair<int,int>&)
```

Which match only #1.

As you don't modify any element, I suggest to add const to each input references.